# Update SQL table through C# code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to update a table through sql code executed in a c# application. To do this, I've used the alter data generated my MSSMS and manually saved it as an sql-file. The c# then reads the file and tries to execute it but it can't. If I use the sql code by itself it works, but not when read by the c# funtion. What's wrong with my c# code?

**The sql code generated my MSSMS:**

```
/* To prevent any potential data loss issues, you should review this script in detail before running it outside the context of the database designer.*/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.tTest ADD
    NewColumn int NULL
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.tTest SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
```

**The c# code that reads it:**

```
string content = string.Empty;
try
{
    content = File.ReadAllText(string.Format(@"C:\temp\{0}.sql", name));
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(content, conn);
    command.Connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command.Connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

**The output that comes from the c# function (the console message):**

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each batch (ended with `GO`) should be sent separately in one `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`. This method is not to be used for multiple batches.

Split your query into several pieces (where `GO` is) and execute it step by step.

Answer (score 0):

The core issue with the script you are trying to run is wrapping a transaction around query batches (A query batch is terminated with a `GO` statement in SQL Server Management Studio).

To do the operations in C# you can execute both statements in one query batch. They do not require to be separate. If you wrap them in one query in a `SqlCommand` object you do not need to handle transactions as there is an "implicit" transaction created.

A last point to look out for is proper disposal of the objects implementing `IDisposable`. The easiest way to do this in C# is by wrapping them in a `using` clause. Once you did that, there is no more need to call the `Close` method on the command/connection objects.

Combining all these remarks gives you the following code:

```
        try
        {
            using(var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            using(var command = new SqlCommand(
                    @"ALTER TABLE dbo.tTest ADD NewColumn int NULL;
                    ALTER TABLE dbo.tTest SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE);", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

Comment: The sql code I had is autogenerated from MSSQL and I dont wish people to edit it for every update of the db